# Square payments: How to protect 'cards on file' from a data breach

Tags: square-connect

I'm in the early stages of integrating Square payments. It makes sense in my application to allow users to save their card details, as we expect multiple small transactions. Square calls this feature 'cards on file'.

As part of this process you create a customer and a related card in Square's system; IDs for these will be held in my system and associated with my users; that way when they come to pay again they can select the option of using a card on file. **The API to actually charge the card simply takes these two IDs and an amount**.

What worries me is that my database is holding all the data necessary to charge a customer's card; I could write a script which just charges all of my customers an amount of money - naturally a hacker with access to my data could do the same thing.

I wasn't expecting to have this level of risk in my system - my assumption was that Square would have isolated me from this (via some sort of user challenge for missing data - e.g. the CCV number). It seems the safe option is to not use the 'card on file' feature and have the user re-enter every time.

Is this right, or have I completely misunderstood something here?

Comment: Being unfamiliar with Square's database structure - when you say that, *"... my database is holding all the data necessary to charge a customer's card,"* are you suggesting that the full plain-text version of the credit card information (16 digits, expiry, CVV, etc.) are all visible from the database without any encryption?  _I highly doubt this is the case,_ given PCI standards.

Comment: Please also read through [Square's PCI compliance and policy notes](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/3796-privacy-and-security) - I do not believe you should have any concerns.  The ID you store locally does not, in itself, open you up to any PCI compliance failures.  It corresponds to Square's database and allows them to take the payment on your behalf without exposing customer information.

Comment: No - Square is holding that data in an opaque manner - there's no way for me to get it. But what I'm saying is that doesn't matter, because I do hold enough information to charge the card any time I like (by calling a Square API).

Comment: That's irrelevant.  Yes, you could charge a customer blindly without them actually requesting to be charged.  That said, so could any vendor.  _Do you think Square would let that situation occur often without revoking your account for fraudulent charges?_  They'd get a handful of phone calls/reversals before they would take action.

Comment: Anyway, this question also has nothing to do with programming.  It's likely better suited for [InfoSec](http://security.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: It's entirely relevant - it's what my question is explicitly asking. Does the square connect API mean I have this level of risk in my system? You seem to have misunderstood that.

Comment: It's still not a question around programming - there's no specific issues with code here, it's literally a matter of security compliance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did miss something - as any charge made on a customer's saved card is credited to my account (as configured in the Square portal), **the only beneficiary of any fraudulent charge would be be me**. A hacker could not get access to funds and therefore the risk is limited in scope.

Obviously if I was a fraudulent company there would be a risk to users - it seems the EU isn't happy with this and changes coming this year will require additional information to be captured from the user at the point of sale.

[Strong Customer Authentication](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/sca-overview)

Answer (score 0):

In order to charge a card, your Square access token is required along with the card ID. It's best practice to store that access token as an environment variable in order to limit the security risk. If someone gains access to the card IDs in your database, they won't be able to charge any of the cards without that access token that's associated with your developer account.